# Summarizing a column in SQL Server after the creation of Pivot table

Tags: sql-server

I cannot summarize numbers in the table (SQL-Server) after pivoting and I will be very grateful for your advice.

Better if I explain the problem on the example:

Existing table:

```
    +-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
    |   #   |   $$$$$   |   Fire    |       Water       |
    +-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
    |   1   |   5       |       1   |   5               |
    |   1   |   4       |       1   |   5               |
    |   1   |   10      |       1   |   5               |
    |   2   |   3       |       3   |   8               |
    |   2   |   4       |       3   |   8               |
    +-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   #   |   $$$$$   |   Fire    |       Water       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   19      |       1   |   5               |
|   2   |   7       |       3   |   8               |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I tend to believe that I already tried all the solutions I found with summarizing and grouping by, but it was not solved, so I rely on you. Thanks in advance. The code I used to create the table:

```
WITH Enerc AS
(
    SELECT  
        a1.[#],
        a1.[$$$$$],
        a2.[cause_of_loss]          
    FROM 
        data1 AS a1
    LEFT JOIN 
        data2 AS a2 ON a1.[id] = a2.[id]
)
SELECT *
FROM Enerc
PIVOT 
    (SUM(gross_claim) FOR [cause_of_loss] IN ([Fire], [Water])) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Your desired result isn't a pivot at all.  No rows are being "pivoted" into columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try group by after the pivot.

```
 With Enerc as
    (SELECT  
        a1.[#],
        a1.[$$$$$],
        a2.[cause_of_loss]

    from data1 as a1
left join data2 as a2
on a1.[id] = a2.[id]
)
select *
into tmp
from Enerc
PIVOT
(sum(gross_claim) 
FOR [cause_of_loss] in (
[Fire], [Water])) 
as PivotTable


select   [#], sum([$$$$$])as [$$$$$],  Fire,   Water 
from #tmp
group by [#],Fire, Water
```

EDIT: in case of permission denied:

```
With Enerc as
    (SELECT  
        a1.[#],
        a1.[$$$$$],
        a2.[cause_of_loss]

    from data1 as a1
left join data2 as a2
on a1.[id] = a2.[id]
),phase2 as(
select *
from Enerc
PIVOT
(sum(gross_claim) 
FOR [cause_of_loss] in (
[Fire], [Water])) 
as PivotTable)
select  [#], sum([$$$$$])as [$$$$$],  Fire,   Water  
from phase2
group by [#],Fire, Water
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But, unfortunately, I do not have a permission "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'."

Comment: Great! Seems like it is going to solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to pivot. Your desired result should be got by grouping and using `SUM`:

```
SELECT  
    a1.[#],
    SUM(a1.[$$$$$]),
    a1.[Fire]
    a1.[Water]  
from data1 as a1
group by  a1.[#],  a1.[Fire], a1.[Water]
```

Let me show an example:

```
DECLARE @Hello TABLE
(
    [#] INT,
    [$$$$$] INT,
    [Fire] INT,
    [Water] INT
)

INSERT INTO @Hello
(
    #,
    [$$$$$],
    Fire,
    Water
)
VALUES
(   1, -- # - int
    5, -- $$$$$ - int
    1, -- Fire - int
    5  -- Water - int
    )
, (1, 4, 1, 5)
, (1, 10, 1, 5)
, (2, 3, 3, 8)
, (2, 4, 3, 8)

SELECT 
h.#, 
SUM(h.[$$$$$]),
h.Fire, 
h.Water 
FROM @Hello h
GROUP BY h.#, h.Fire, h.Water
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my real Query is much bigger with 90000 lines and pivoting into 30 columns, I am not sure it is doable without the Pivot at all. But I will try.

Comment: @Nihat post your real/sample data and desired output in your new question as now we’ve answered how to make your desired output.